# Marshalling Error by callback

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

When my callback is called I get:

> Marshalling Error has occurred.

What is "Marshalling" ?? and why my callback is invalid. please tell me.

here is the codes.

```
   public Page1()//constructor
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += new Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler(OnNetworkStatusChanged);//regist callback
    }

    void OnNetworkStatusChanged(object arg)//callback method
    {
        App.mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }
```

Comment: In few words, "marshalling" refers to the process of converting the data or the objects inbto a byte-stream, and "unmarshalling" is the reverse process of converting the byte-stream back to their original data or object. The conversion is achieved through "serialization".

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I understood what is "Marshalling".but I could'nt figure out relevance of the error and my codes...

Comment: i dont know it ether but if it helped you then it was a help that was why it was a comment and not a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the 'Navigate' method is being executed on the wrong thread (and needs to be marshalled, so that it is called on the right thread).

In Windows8, code that interacts with the UI should be executed only on the UI thread - and call-back methods (such as your `OnNetworkStatusChanged` method above) do not necessarily get called on the UI thread.  To ensure that code is executed on the UI thread, and not some other thread, use an idiom like:

```
// somewhere in your code behind, in code that definitely runs on the UI thread
// - e.g. in the OnLoaded method of your main window:
CoreDispatcher Dispatcher = Windows.UI.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher; 


// In your call-back method:
if ((Dispatcher != null) && (!Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess))
{
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                (obj, invokedArgs) => { App.mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));}, 
                this, 
                null
     );
}
else
    App.mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
```